# What does "take call for someone" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

It's from a Tweet:

One person named *Eugene Gu* said:

> I'm an Asian-American doctor and today I #TakeTheKnee to fight white
>   supremacy.

And a man named *Thomas Stratton* replied:

> Dr. Gu, I'll never take call for you. But I will #TakeTheKnee with you
>   to fight white supremacy because I know #WhiteSilenceIsWhiteViolence

[image]

Comment: It's a typo (mistake) and makes no sense. I'm struggling to work out what it should be.

Comment: This does not appear to be a typo, based on a quick web search. It appears to be medical lingo related to being "on call". Not in medicine myself, so I'm not sure the exact meaning.

Comment: It's "unnatural" phrasing riffing off recently high-profile non-grammatical ***take the knee***. There's nothing to learn about English ***grammar*** here - just "Twitterspeak".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica "riffing" off?

Comment: See [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riff) and [this related earlier ELL question.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245123/what-is-the-meaning-of-two-young-men-who-are-riffs-on-gangsters-films-archetype)

Comment: It's at least *possible* that if one doctor offers to cover another's "on call" shift (where the doctor might not actually have to go in to work at all; he's simply being paid to be ***immediately available*** if required), he might actually make that offer by saying ***I will take call for you.*** I seriously doubt that anyway, but even if it ***was*** a "domain-specific usage", there wouldn't be much point in you learning it. Almost no other native speakers would know it (or *none at all*, since it probably has *no* currency whatsoever), and we all communicate just fine without it!

Answer (score 2):

*Call* here is common jargon in U.S. medicine, and perhaps elsewhere, referring to the duty to be available on short notice outside of regular working hours as part of one's employment. This is the same sense of *call* as in *[call schedule](https://www.cumc.columbia.edu/harlem-hospital/surgery-residency/program/Resident%20Hours%20and%20Call%20Schedule)* and *[call roster](https://books.google.com/books?id=PORTzqCiTdIC&pg=PA771&lpg=PA771&dq=%22call%20roster%22#v=onepage&q=%22call%20roster%22&f=false)*

It is taken from the expression *[on-call](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/on-call)* (OALD):

> [only before noun] *(especially North American English)*
> (of a doctor, police officer, etc.) available for work if necessary, especially in an emergency

In turn, this derives from *call* in the sense of a request or demand made of someone.

You can think of *call* as a type of shift, somewhat analogous to *duty* or *watch* in the military, though the nature of it differs somewhat by role, specialty, and experience. For example, for a new doctor in training (known as a *resident* in the American system), call entails being at the hospital for 28 hours at a time, filling in for other doctors or assisting with surges in demand. At the next level (*attending*), you do not need to be present at the hospital while on call, but you can never be far from either the hospital or from a telephone as you might be asked to come in on short notice. As you can imagine, call is very unpopular.

The tweet is a play on words. The replier says to Dr. Gu that although he would never take Gu's call duty—that being too undesirable—he will happily *take a knee* ([genuflect](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/genuflect?q=genuflect)) with him.

Comment: Maybe the Twitterer, Thomas Stratton, is just stating a fact: he is not a doctor and could never be "on call" but there's one thing he can do, and that is share "taking the knee" with Dr. Gu. If TS is also a medic, you cannot tell by reading the Tweet.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good point; it isn't necessary for the respondent to be a doctor, since the reference is facetious to begin with. It's like me saying I won't be donating any of my millions to the Trump campaign—I don't have any millions to begin with.